# Ignore parent rotation

Tags: objects, light, parent

I'm currently playing around with small projects using different functions and effects to improve my skills in the software, however, I've run into a challenge in my current project that I can't seem to solve.

I have a coin (I've given it a colorful texture in the picture, in order to make it more visible to you). This coin spins into the view, and when it stops, et tips backward on one of the sites.

I have 3 light sources in the scene. Two lights are tracking the position of the coin so they keep rotating in the direction of the coin, but they stay in the same position at all times.

The remaining light - the one selected in the picture - is parented to the coin. I want this light to move along the coin at all times, but when the coin tips on its side at the end, I don't want the light to rotate along with it, but instead keep staying exactly above the coins pivot point.

I've tried locking all transformations of the light before the coin tips, and then when the coin has tipped, I move the light back in the position I want it to be in, and then I lock all transformations again, but the moment I drag across the timeline, it doesn't save the new position I have assigned.

How can I make this work? Can I somehow parent the light to the coins location while ignoring the rotation?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the copy location constraint. Give the spot light a copy location constraint and set the coin as the target and check the offset option so the spot light won't be exactly at the location of the coin but above it.

[image: Copy location]

More info on manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/transform/copy_location.html

Comment: Just a suggestion, but I would change to the default blender theme before taking screenshots. Some users (particularly new ones) might find it difficult to locate the areas in the screenshot  if their theme differs a lot.

Comment: @Ray Mairlot thx for the suggestion, i'll change back my theme next time i take screenshots

Comment: Thanks a lot... I hadn't even spared constraint a thought, but it surely did the trick.